# How refractive index is related to speed of light in mediums?

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed-of-light, refraction, geometric-optics

Snell's law tells us that,

Sine of angle of incident of light by sine of angle of refraction of light, when light travels from one medium to other, is a constant(for that mediums).

It is also related as ratio of speed of light in two mediums. This ratio is also a constant.

But, how they both are equal? How we came up with this?

Comment: are you asking how is the ratio of velocities equal to ratio of sine of angles ?

Comment: Yes , how we came up with it?

Comment: Is this answer helpful  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/334152/271783

Comment: Yeah it is   Thanks